# Character is deformed after parenting a rig and playing animation

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature

I imported my character that I made into a file that has a rig, I aligned the rig with my character in pose mode. Then I parented the character to the Rig. Then it parented but my mesh is completely deformed when I play the animation, there seems to be a smaller duplicate version of my arms and legs and they are in different parts of the body and are stretched. I've been trying to fix this the whole day but couldn't find a solution. Can anyone provide a solution?

Link to blend file: (Edit:Blend file is 211mb for some reason, Blend Exchange also said there was an internal error, so if you would like, I can share using drive or mega)

Screenshots:

Topology of character(I used Triangulate modifier because a lot of faces were triangles but not all so I used triangulate modifier):
[image: it has 9960 triangles]

Deformed character:
[image: Very deformed]

Comment: Have you checked the mesh for duplicate vertices? (in *Edit* mode press key A to select all, key M > *Merge By Distance*). The topology of your character looks like a sculpt. For animation it's better to have a clean topology. Have you already watched a tutorial on this topic?

Comment: Hi, I have watched a tutorial, I have been doing research and realized that I had applied a solidify modifier to my mesh so the rig only added weight to the outer part of the mesh and not the inner, so I just deleted the inner part of the mesh and re parented the mesh, the duplication problem is gone, but I think you’re right about there topology. thank you for the suggestion